# Access key value pair in generic object

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-3, object

I have a generic object populated like this:

```
object cAdditional;

cAdditional = defaultCols.ContainsKey(colType + "adtlParams") && defaultCols[colType + "adtlParams"] != ""
              ? serializer.Deserialize<object>(defaultCols[colType + "adtlParams"])
              : null;
```

I don't know which elements will be returned (if any), but can see the results in debugger like this:

[image]

if I try to access the object like this cAdditional[0], I get the error: `Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'`

I have a class that is expecting the keys (`summaryType` in this example) so I would like to do something like this:

```
var colMod = new ColModel
                 {
                    summaryType = cAdditional["summaryType"]
                    summaryTpl = cAdditional["summaryTpl"]
                 };
```

I can't see to even access any of the key/values let alone specify which.

Additionally, there is no guarantee that `summaryType` will be the 0 element, so I have to get the Value by the Key.

How do I attach this?

Comment: Have you tried making the cAdditional a dynamic instead of an object?

Comment: can you declare cAdditional as an IDictionary or Ilist<KeyValuePair>?  or even do var cAdditional = ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can see the results in debugger

That's because the debugger is looking at the type that `cAdditional` *really* is at runtime and is able to show you its properties/methods.  Since the compiler only knows at compile time that `cAdditional` is an `object` it cannot bind to a string indexer.

You need to cast `cAdditional` to the type it's supposed to be to bind to the indexer or use `dynamic` to bind to the string indexer at runtime.

Either method is susceptible to run-time failure.